# Is it possible to make this formula more automated?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Basically, my formula works exactly how I need it to right now. However, there's still more manual entry than I'd like having to do. It's minimal, but if I can eliminate it altogether it's all the better.

My current formula is `=IFERROR(INDEX(RawData[value], MATCH(1, (RawData[plot_id]=$A2)*(RawData[class]=1)*(RawData[metric]=LEFT($B1,FIND("(",$B1)-1)), 0)),0)`. This can be seen in the *Test Organized Tab* image below.

I still have to manually change the class number for each formula when I move it to a new column (the class number each column is searching for is the parenthetical number in that column's header: (1), (2), (5)). I've tried replacing `RawData[class]=1` with `RawData[class]=MID(B1, SEARCH("(", B1)+1, SEARCH(")", B1) - SEARCH("(", B1) -1)`, but it breaks the formula and will only give me the error result of 0.

However, if I use the same MID (`=MID(B1, SEARCH("(", B1)+1, SEARCH(")", B1) - SEARCH("(", B1) -1)`) function in a cell on its own, I get exactly the result I'm looking for: the number between the parenthesis in the header cell of the column (which can be seen in cell B4 of the previously mentioned screenshot.

I'm at a loss because it allows me to successfully use the LEFT function when searching for the RawData[metric] criteria.

Any idea what's going on here or how I can get this to work?

---

### Raw Data Table (generic data)

| metric | class | plot_id | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| area_mn | 1 | 1 | 0.720177968 |
| area_mn | 1 | 2 | 0.005311753 |
| area_mn | 2 | 1 | 0.011488774 |
| area_mn | 2 | 2 | 0.435016987 |
| ed | 5 | 1 | 0.1856209 |

**Screenshot for Visual Reference**

[image: Raw Data Image]

---

### Organized Data Table (generic data, showing desired result)

| plot_id | area_mn(1) | area_mn(2) | ed(5) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.720177968 | 0.01148877 | 0.720177968 |
| 2 | 0.005311753 | 0.435016987 | 0 |

**Screenshot for Visual Reference**
[image: Test Organized Tab Image2]

Comment: Have you tried using absolute references in your `MID` function? So instead of `B1` use `B$1`? Also, don't provide your text as an image. Without any copy-pasteable table someone who wants to help needs to retype your data and formulas. That's quite a big ask. Could you [edit] your question to include a small example subset?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke Edited because I completely misinterpreted your comment before. Completely my bad. I've not tried using absolutes. That may be something to try. And my apologies, I'll edit my post for a more complete/useful read. :)

Comment: I believe the issue is the `MID` formula is a text while your `RawData[class]` is a number, wrap your `MID` with `VALUE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

After messing with it for awhile this morning, I wasn't able to get the formula to work correctly using exact responses I got—I still keep getting incorrect data when filling the cell across and down the rest of my table, but all of you have been very helpful, and I appreciate your time and help.

For the final formula, I came up with `=IFERROR(INDEX(RawData[[value]:[value]], MATCH(1, (RawData[[plot_id]:[plot_id]]=$A2)*(RawData[[class]:[class]]=-MID(B$1, SEARCH("(", B$1), 3))*(RawData[[metric]:[metric]]=LEFT(B$1,FIND("(",B$1)-1)), 0)),0)`.

@MGonet I appreciate your comment that helped reduce the portion of the formula that was pulling the class number. This thing got long enough as is. Lol.

For additional explanation: I realized my table columns were shifting when I would autofill the data across my table. I didn't realize they would do that, I thought specifying a table column was always an absolute reference—today I learned otherwise. So I corrected those references to make them absolute.

After that, I basically took bits and pieces of all of the advise and suggestions from here (e.g. correcting areas where I typo'd the absolute cell reference I was making, using more condensed function alternatives, etc.), plus my own additional research and some more trial and error, and was able to get a formula that does exactly what I need.

Seriously, thank you all so much for your time!

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an issue with incompatible datatypes in the `RawData[class]=1` part.

Presumably `class` in `RawData` is a number (no way to know, as you didn't include any data).
When you write `1` yourself, Excel understands that it is a number and uses that for the comparison. When you use the `MID()` formula to extract that number for example from the string `area_mn(1)`, you get back a string that is `1`. The number `1` is not equal to the string `1`, so the comparison fails.

If you wrap that `MID()` function in an `INT()` formula, the string gets converted to an integer (a number) and the comparison works again.

Here is an example:

**Data table**

| id | area_mn(1) | area_mn(2) | area_mn(5) | ed(1) | ed(2) | ed(5) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 |  |  |  |  |  |  |

**Lookup table**

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 200 |
| 3 | 300 |
| 4 | 400 |
| 5 | 500 |

If you use below formula in your data table you'll get `#N/A`:

```
=INDEX(lookup[#Data], MATCH(MID(B$1,SEARCH("(",B$1)+1,SEARCH(")",B$1)-SEARCH("(",B$1)-1),lookup[[id]:[id]], 0), 2)
```

But if you convert the looked up value to an integer first, it works:

```
=INDEX(lookup[#Data], MATCH(INT(MID(B$1,SEARCH("(",B$1)+1,SEARCH(")",B$1)-SEARCH("(",B$1)-1)),lookup[[id]:[id]], 0), 2)
```

Comment: If your class number is always a number in parentheses at the end of text you can simplify your formula to extract it as a number. Try `=-REPLACE(B1,1,SEARCH("(",B1)-1,"")` or `=-MID(B1, SEARCH("(", B1), 10)`. If you convert text `(1)` to a number you get negative value. This is why you need to add minus before.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke You are correct, wrapping my MID function in the INT function does allow the formula to continue functioning properly; however, that's only true for the first cell I implemented the formula into (B2, in this case). When I fill the formula throughout the rest of the table I get the value I'm looking for returned in a few cells, but mostly the error value of 0, even in cells where my current formula fills correct value. I appreciate the time you took with this, and the INT suggestion helps. I'll edit my original post to be more helpful and will let you know when that's done.

Comment: Use $ in addresses where appropriate.

Comment: @MGonet good suggestion, feel free to edit my answer to include it.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your table headers are a combination of the [metric] and [class] values from your RawData table. You could probably make things easier on yourself by using a single delimiter, such as a "." or "," or ";" rather than using both opening and closing parenthesis, especially if your [class] values are only single digits. That way you could just use `=VALUE(RIGHT(B$1,1))` or `=INT(RIGHT(B$1,1))` or `=--RIGHT(B$1,1)` to extract the number. For example:

| plot_id | area_mn.1 | area_mn.2 | area_mn.5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |  |
| 3 |  |  |  |

With the headers formatted in this manner, the following formula would work in cell B2:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(RawData[value], MATCH(1, (RawData[plot_id]=$A2)*(RawData[class]=VALUE(RIGHT(B$1,1)))*(RawData[metric]=LEFT(B$1,FIND(".",B$1)-1)), 0)), 0)
```

Note the absolute cell references $A2 (absolute column) and B$1 (absolute row) used above. In your original attempt, you had incorrectly used $B1 (absolute column) on the header row, which is why it wouldn't copy down and across properly.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion! Unfortunately this is a project I'm working on for someone else, and they want them parenthetically. But I'll make the suggestion to them because I wouldn't be surprised if they just had thought of something like this—and I'm sure they don't realize how much easier it would be with Excel.

Comment: Fair enough. This would work then, with parentheses, if all of your [class] values are single digits: `=IFERROR(INDEX(RawData[value], MATCH(1, (RawData[plot_id]=$A2)*(RawData[class]=-RIGHT(B$1,3))*(RawData[metric]=LEFT(B$1,FIND("(",B$1)-1)), 0)), 0)`. RIGHT is simpler than MID with SEARCH.

Comment: After I sent them the file and was explaining how the formula was working, I started wondering if RIGHT was a better option. It significantly reduces the formula length too!! :) I’ve never had to get very complex with Excel. This is actually the first time I’ve used most of these functions. It’s definitely been a valuable learning experience into the options there are and the easiest way to approach a formula like this.